# Calculate vehicles Movement using GPS- latitude & longitude

Tags: geometry, 3d

I am getting GPS data every 5 Sec.

I need to track vehicles turns (Left ,Right, angle in Degree ) using GPS latitude, longitude ,Altitude value.

But got confused in calculating vehicles turns.

Example : Vehicle Moved from Point A (latitude_1,longitude_1, Altitude_1) to Point B (latitude_2,longitude_2, Altitude_2), from Point B to Point C (latitude_3,longitude_3, Altitude_3).

So during vehicle moments from point A to B & B to C, is vehicle taken any turns (Left, Right Or Straight) ?

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just considering points you can't tell.  Given two points there is a straight line between them and also an infinite number of paths with 90 degree turns left and right.  You can do a couple things.  Vehicles usually do not turn so often, so you can look for a series of points that fit a straight line.  When you find a point that doesn't fit the line so well, see if the next series of points fits a line.  Find the intersection of these two lines and assume that is where the vehicle turned.  Another is to assume the vehicle is on a road, figure out what road it is on, and when the road turns.  When it gets onto another road, it usually turns and the map will tell you how much.  Both of these approaches need some work to deal with errors in the coordinates that are measured.  You need to do some filtering of the data in any case.